# title vs <title>

Tags: bug

I stumbled across [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/562586/is-it-possible-to-measure-hba-throughput-using-perfmon-on-windows-server-2008-r2) and noticed that the question title didn't match the tab title (i.e. the title that comes from the html  tag). In this case it looks like "storage area network -" is prepended to the html title.

Shouldn't they be the same? It doesn't appear to be due to an edit (unless it was an author edit that I can't see).

[image: My view from firefox]

Comment: Following a system I don't understand, sometimes one of the questions tags are added to the `<title>` of the page. In this case, it was the `storage area networks` tag. This has something to do to prevent downranks by Google if your content get's scraped (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71906/first-tag-in-the-title-of-the-page-is-not-that-convenient and http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6556/does-the-order-of-keywords-matter-in-a-page-title). Thank god I can 100% ignore any SEO for my job ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was to downgrade the google results of dumb scrapers. They would just take the crappy title and put all their SEO efforts into it, whereas the Stack Exchange network has excellent SEO even with the dumb titles.

I know there is a meta.stackexchange post from years ago about it but I'm on mobile and can't find it right now.